# Deleting Temporary Files after usage

Tags: .net, windows, temporary-files

I need to work with some temporary files in my Windows Forms .NET 3.5 application. Those files are opened in an external application that can of course be running for a longer time than my own program.

Are there any best practices to make sure these temporary files are cleaned up at any time in order to avoid filling the user's hard disk with "junk" files which aren't needed anymore? Or does even Windows kind of handle this automatically?

A nice example is any mail client: When you open an attachment in any application, it is usually written to a temporary file which is opened. Is there a way to figure out how those files manage cleanup?

Using Google has shown me many, many cleanup and tune-up tools to clean the temp directory by hand, but I'd not like to force the users to do so. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you attempt to deterministically clear the contents of a Temporary Files type folder, you risk removing files that are in use by other processes.  The Windows operating system provides tools to allow users to remove those files when the volume's available disk space reaches a certain threshold.

Now, if you can determine that after you use a specific temporary file that it will no longer be needed, then there's no down-side to deleting that specific file.

Comment: Yeah, atm I'm catching the Process' Exit-event to delete files that aren't needed anymore for sure... so, is it good practice to "encourage" the user to use the Windows Disk Cleanup tool? :)

Answer (score 28):

In .NET you can use the `TempFileCollection` class for managing a set of temporary files to be cleaned up by your application (Note that it is rather hidden in the CodeDom namespace). Obviously you can't delete any files not owned by yourself, because the files might still be opened by another application (and deleting them might cause serious issues).

Comment: TempFileCollection class?  Hot!

Comment: Indeed ;-) Don't know why this class is so well-hidden. If not by accident you wouldn't find it...

Comment: Wow, no more hand-rolled solutions, seems like Microsoft implements everything 2 years after we need it ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this class!  But, it doesn't solve the OP's problem (temp files may need to live longer than your application, but not forever).

Comment: Watching how Outlook handles temporary files (for preview and launching attachments), they put them in the temporary folder, and try to delete them when Outlook closes. Very similar in practice to what the `TempFileCollection` does.

Answer (score 7):

The responsibility for cleaning up temporary files ought to be on the application that created them. It is very easy. I use a class that looks something like this:

```
public class TempFile : IDisposable
{
    public TempFile()
    { this.path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName(); }

    public void Dispose()
    { File.Delete(path); }

    private string path;
    public string Path { get { return path; } }
}
```

If you are required to clean up another application's temporary files it needs some means of communicating with yours. At a minimum it should be able to provide a semaphore. However the complexity of doing this is greater than the complexity of just having the originating application take care of its own files.

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar file lifetime problem - the (winforms) application can fetch a document from a central repository store for the user to view, but the user should be able to close our app without it affecting the file they are viewing. Due to security concerns the document files need to be cleaned up so they aren't lying around too long.

The solution we use is to create a folder with a date-derived name in the users' isolated storage area and use that as today's cache. At application close-down and start-up we check for previous dated cache folders and delete them (and contents).

Answer (score 1):

I believe they will be deleted when the user logs out.

Back in the days when people turned off their pcs every day, that was probably a perfect solution.

Now, people can potentially go months without logging off, so it may not be a good idea to rely on that.

Also, if they turn their machine off without shutting down then the files won't get deleted either.

You could use a file system watcher that watches the file you write, and wait for some period of inactivity (10 minuites, 1 hour, 1 day, or what ever) and then delete the file.

That won't work for everything though. Some programs may have a file "open", but might not have the underlying file locked. If that happens, then you would have no way of knowing when it's safe to delete the file.

However, I'm thinking you can probably just ignore the problem. Most people probably have a surplus of hard drive space anyways, so they probably aren't likely to run into it. If they do, I think Windows pops up a low disk space dialog that gives them the option to clear their temp directory, which would solve the problem.

**Update:**

I think Windows Update will restart the user's computer about once a month, so the temp files should be cleared when that happens.

There's no guarantee that there won't be problems, but in practice I think it should be pretty rare.

**Update 2:**

Prompted by a comment, I went and actually tested this, and it looks like windows doesn't delete the temp files when the user logs out. However, I still say that in the OP's case, this isn't a real problem. When it becomes a problem (because disk space is low) Windows will prompt the user to delete temporary files.

Comment: You want to rely on there being a Windows update? And that the update will require a restart? And that the user hasn't disable autorunning of updates?

Comment: I'm saying that its not a big deal if you leave stuff in the temp folder. 

There are several ways windows will automatically delete the files. 

Even if it doesn't it's only a problem if disk space gets low. 

When that happens, the user sees a dialog that says "here's how to fix this".

Comment: On a default configuration, Windows will not clean up any files from your temp folder (unless you run Cleanmgr.exe when you get the balloon tip that your drive is not having enough free disc space, but I wouldn't call that automatic).

Comment: And, by the way it's possible even with Windows to keep your system up and running for more than a month ;-)

Comment: My point is still that it doesn't matter. It's only a problem when you use up ALL the disk space, or when the customer notices his disk space is low, and when that happens the temp folder will get deleted.

Comment: I think you're right, Scott. But taking a look at my own profile's temp directory tells me the oldest files are just a few days old. May there be another "secret" feature of Windows keeping the temp directory clean...? I'll google this when I have some time.

Answer (score 1):

When using temporary files in ASP.NET, use the PAGE_DISPOSED event to delete any temporary files you created in the page. Otherwise you may end up with contention with components that do not let go until DISPOSED.

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution (quite reliable):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Konard.Helpers
{
    public static partial class TemporaryFiles
    {
        private const string UserFilesListFilenamePrefix = ".used-temporary-files.txt";
        static private readonly object UsedFilesListLock = new object();

        private static string GetUsedFilesListFilename()
        {
            return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + UserFilesListFilenamePrefix;
        }

        private static void AddToUsedFilesList(string filename)
        {
            lock (UsedFilesListLock)
            {
                using (var writer = File.AppendText(GetUsedFilesListFilename()))
                    writer.WriteLine(filename);
            }
        }

        public static string UseNew()
        {
            var filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
            AddToUsedFilesList(filename);
            return filename;
        }

        public static void DeleteAllPreviouslyUsed()
        {
            lock (UsedFilesListLock)
            {
                var usedFilesListFilename = GetUsedFilesListFilename();

                if (!File.Exists(usedFilesListFilename))
                    return;

                using (var listFile = File.Open(usedFilesListFilename, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(listFile))
                    {
                        string tempFileToDelete;
                        while ((tempFileToDelete = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(tempFileToDelete))
                                File.Delete(tempFileToDelete);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Clean up
                using (File.Open(usedFilesListFilename, FileMode.Truncate)) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every time you need temporary file use:

```
var tempFile = TemporaryFiles.UseNew();
```

To be sure all temporary files are deleted after application closes or crashes put

```
TemporaryFiles.DeleteAllPreviouslyUsed();
```

at start of the application.

Answer (score 0):

- you can create one temp file, in which you can keep writing the file names created during the process, at the end of processing may be you can (precondition - Implement IDisposable and) delete in the Disponse method after operation is completed.
- Other way is write independent process which perform cleanup every interval.
- Attache the date at the end of the file, and delete at the end of the day with that date, and process will generate new files wiht new date at the end.
- one good suggestion given by divo tempfilecollection class.

hope it helps.